# How to add a CKEditor instance between two CKEditor instances?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have allocated unique ids for CKEditor instances on my web application.When adding a new CKEditor, server sends a unique ID and new CKEditor's position relative to existing instances.

How to add a new instance with a unique received id between existing CK Editor instances?

PS: The concept of bodyclass and bodyid exist now but they are for body element of the editing area.But here I want to specify ID for the whole CKEditor instance.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code that receives the new ID and creates the new editor instance.  Also, please explain meaning of "add a new instance ...between existing instances", i.e., what is the purpose.

Comment: @Roberto - Sorry if I was not clear.Suppose there are two CKEditor instances on the web page. I want to add a CKEditor instance between these two existing instance.I cannot explain in simpler language than this.

Comment: @Roberto - Also do not go into details how I get this ID. For simplicity suppose I have ID - 'ckeditor1001'.Now how to create CKEditor instance with this ID.CKEditor instances by default take the ID of forms - 'cke_editor1' or 'cke_editor2'.The no. at the end depends on the number of existing ck editor instances on the web page.